# Is there any way that i cant get friend list of any user by his Facebook User Id or username?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way that i can get friend list of any of my friends by using their user id or username??

I used FBfriendPickerDelegate to get my friend list but how can i get others friendlists by their id?

**UPDATE** **THE ANSWER**
I found a solution for it

```
    FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error) {

    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    NSString * friendListString = @"" ;

    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
        NSLog (@"Friend Name %@,Friend ID %@",friend.name,friend.id);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Only with a valid access_token and permissions otherwise the ability to abuse this and spam people would be too great. A user must explicitly grant your app access to their friends/friendlists for you to access them

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-friends

Answer (score 1):

Since Apr 30th's Facebook API v2.0, it's no longer possible to get any of your friends information (all user_* permission were removed).